# Monotonicity of n-th root by induction

Tags: inequality, induction

Suppose a,b are real numbers. I'm trying to prove that

$\forall n\geq 1$ ( $0<a<b$    entails   $0 <a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}$  )

with the method of **Induction**.

P.S : I already know how to prove by contradiction.

*$n=1$*

This is easy to prove.

*Inductive Hypothesis*

Assume $0 <a^{\frac{1}{k}} <b^{\frac{1}{k}}$ .

I need to reach $0 <a^{1/(k+1)}<b^{1/(k+1)}$   .

I've found that $\frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k(k+1)} $.

So, if i can find the following inequation :

$0 <a^{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}} <b^{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}}  $

We could divide the inductive hypothesis by it and reach the conclusion ... but i'm not sure this is the way to go ( i can't derive that one either ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, given that $a,b>0$ and you are considering only the real root that is also greater than zero, you could *technically* just raise $a$ and $b$ to the $(k+1)/k$ power, and that would land you back at your inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Of course, I doubt that's what you're looking for.